# ASP.NET MvcMailer error

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, mvcmailer

When sending mail from localhost, all works without problems

### error occurs after publishing site on server

[image]
**

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 8.8.246.37:25

**

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Looks like a firewall issue, either on your server, the router or the receiving end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outgoing SMTP connection may be blocked by a firewall. It is a standard outgoing spam prevention measure.

Do you get SMTP greeting message using telnet (command line program)?

```
telnet 8.8.246.37 25
```

If you can not contact port 25 then try port 587.

```
telnet 8.8.246.37 587
```